# Confusion on one_to_many relationships Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, one-to-many

I am confused about how to assign multiple tags to one menu item.

If I have a new Menu Item named 'Tacos', I want this menu item to have the tags 'Spicy' and 'Protein' assigned to it.

Similarly, if I have a new Menu Item named 'Steak', I want to apply the same 'Protein' tag to this item. Is this possible?

```
class MenuTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu_item
end

class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_tags
end

food_one = MenuItem.new(name: "Tacos", tags: NOT SURE WHAT GOES HERE???)
food_two = MenuItem.new(name: "Steak", tags: NOT SURE WHAT GOES HERE???)

spicy = MenuTag.new(name: "Spicy", menu_item_id: 1)
protein = MenuTag.new(name: "Protein, menu_item_id: 1,2) <---- can I assign two id's here???
```

Comment: What you want is called a has and belongs to many (HABTM) relation. And there is two ways to implement it on Rails. Know that you know the name it should be easier to find the right documentation.

Comment: Don't you think you are doing reverse of what one-to-many means? If a menu item has many tags then how can you pass two menu item ids for a tag?

Comment: should this be a many-to-many then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you use it:

```
food_one = MenuItem.create(name: "Tacos", menu_tags: [menu_tag_1, menu_tag_2, ...])
food_one.menu_tags.create(name: "Spicy")
```

or the other way around:

```
MenuTag.create(name: "Protein", menu_item: food_one)# using instances
MenuTag.create(name: "Protein", menu_item_id: food_one.id) # using ids
```

NOTE: you need to have a created item before relate to them.

Comment: Thanks @RaVeN. I am still confused how to assign multiple instances?

    food_two = MenuItem.create(name: "Steak")

    MenuTag.create(name: "Protein", menu_item: food_one, food_two)